# GWT 2.3 WeakMapping/ProxyAutoBean memory leaks

Tags: hibernate, gwt, memory, memory-leaks, requestfactory

I have been experiencing some nasty OutOfMemory exceptions on our Tomcat test server. Our web application uses GWT 2.3 & GXT on the client side, Spring 3.0 on the server side,Hibernate 3.6.3 & JPA.

I have made some heap dumps with VisualVM and opened them with Memory Analizer Tool to see what was occupying so much space. Today, the heap was occupied 900-950MB of 1GB available and the most memory was accumulated in org.apache.catalina.WebAppClassLoader (680MB) which contained a huge 671 MB entry of com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.WeakMapping (671MB). I saw there were lots of objects of type ProxyAutobean and also a lot of the Hibernate entities.

I searched online and found [something](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6193)  which could apply to my case but I'm not sure if/how I can solve it this way without having to upgrade to a later version of GWT. As it seems, this leak is caused by using circular references between entities/proxies which we do have in our code.

Any suggestions, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try "patching" your dependency (or *monkey patching*: adding patched classes earlier in the classpath), but it's way easier to just upgrade.

Request Factory has a stable protocol, so you can very well use GWT 2.3 on the client side and Request Factory 2.4 on the server side; you'll then just experiment the leak in DevMode, on the client-side, but not in production on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. However, if I try upgrading only the RequestFactory part, I get validation problems regarding an interface which extends ClientBundle. If I try upgrading GWT as a whole to 2.4, I get an exception at runtime: "The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for "myRequestFactory" RequestFactory type". I would prefer then to upgrade GWT to 2.4.0, do you know an easier way to do it and get rid of the validation RF problems?
"

Comment: About that last message, see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation

Comment: Hello, I tried downloading the m2e-apt connector on Springsource Toolsuite 2.6.1 but: 
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT 1.0.0.. (org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.feature.feature.group 1.0.0..)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT Core 1.0.0.. (org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.core 1.0.0..) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT 1.0.0.. (org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.feature.feature.group 1.0.0..)
    To: org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.core [1.0.0..]

Comment: Try with the previous version then, without m2e-apt: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11019